# Cannot change the background colour of <SideNav>

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm using react and I came across a side navbar that I like. However I cannot change it from the default `red` background colour. I tried making my own custom css, and trying entering `className: bg-dark` etc on any line possible and it isn't working? Can anyone help? Also here is a link to the side where I found this navbar: https://reactjsexample.com/react-side-nav-component/

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Navbar } from "react-bootstrap";
import SideNav, { Toggle, Nav, NavItem, NavIcon, NavText } from '@trendmicro/react-sidenav';
import '@trendmicro/react-sidenav/dist/react-sidenav.css';
import Routes from "./Routes";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App container">
      <SideNav
        onSelect={(selected) => {
            // Add your code here
        }}
      >
        <SideNav.Toggle />
        <SideNav.Nav defaultSelected="home">
            <NavItem eventKey="home">
                <NavIcon>
                    <i className="fa fa-fw fa-home" style={{ fontSize: '1.75em' }} />
                </NavIcon>
                <NavText>
                    <Link to="/">Scratch</Link>
                </NavText>
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem eventKey="sites">
                <NavIcon>
                    <i className="fa fa-fw fa-line-chart" style={{ fontSize: '1.75em' }} />
                </NavIcon>
                <NavText>
                    <Link to="/sites">Sites</Link>
                </NavText>
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem eventKey="tours">
                <NavIcon>
                    <i className="fa fa-fw fa-line-chart" style={{ fontSize: '1.75em' }} />
                </NavIcon>
                <NavText>
                    <Link to="/tours">Tours</Link>
                </NavText>
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem eventKey="media">
                <NavIcon>
                    <i className="fa fa-fw fa-line-chart" style={{ fontSize: '1.75em' }} />
                </NavIcon>
                <NavText>
                    <Link to="/media">Media</Link>
                </NavText>
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem eventKey="newSite">
                <NavIcon>
                    <i className="fa fa-fw fa-line-chart" style={{ fontSize: '1.75em' }} />
                </NavIcon>
                <NavText>
                    <Link to="/newSite">Add new Site</Link>
                </NavText>
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem eventKey="profile">
                <NavIcon>
                    <i className="fa fa-fw fa-line-chart" style={{ fontSize: '1.75em' }} />
                </NavIcon>
                <NavText>
                    <Link to="/profile">Profile</Link>
                </NavText>
            </NavItem>

        </SideNav.Nav>
      </SideNav>
      <Routes />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: please add a working link with css

Comment: Have you tried to import your own CSS, after the import off @trendmicro/react-sidenav/dist/react-sidenav.css ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.sidenav---_u0En{
  background: yourcolor
}
```

if it still doesn't work add `!important`

OR

your code doesn't work most likely because you are using `background-color` try changing it to `background`

Comment: !important is nice to use if you need to make a quick fix, but it is horrible to maintain, so always be careful when using !important :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by putting an **id**

```
<SideNav
      onSelect={(selected) => {
        // Add your code here
      }}
      onToggle={onToggle}
      id="sdb"
   >
```

in css:

```
#sdb{
    background-color: #120A8F;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The SideNav component allow to use a custom className, but there is something wrong during the classNames merge.

`<SideNav className="menu" > ... </SideNav>`

This code add your class `.menu` at the first, so your CSS styles is crashed bug the SideNav default classes.

The problem is at [this line](https://github.com/trendmicro-frontend/react-sidenav/blob/master/src/SideNav.jsx#L130)

Look at [this issue](https://github.com/trendmicro-frontend/react-sidenav/issues/17)

Answer (score 0):

```
<SideNav style={{'background-color': 'red'}}></SideNav>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)" 
before asking a question.